# Understanding Oasis findlibParent's purpose

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamlfind, oasis

I am currently working on a project where I am using Oasis to handling building of the OCaml files. It works great. However I am confused at what `findlibParent` is actually doing in a library definition.

The documentation specifies

> FindlibParent: Library which includes the current library. The current library will be built as its parents and installed along it.

I dont understand what implication `built as its parents` has on the way I refer to something. Does this mean if I have module library that has `findlibParent: X` in the definition, and the module's name is `Y`, then I would have to refer to it like `open X.Y`?

I apologize if this is obvious - the wording is very confusing to me.

Thank you!

Comment: I am not an user of Oasis, but I guess it is bit module hierarchy but finblib(ocamlfind) library hierarchy. If you have `findlibParent: x` and the current library is named `y`, then the current will be installed with `x` using `ocamlfind install`.  As the result, the current will be available ocamlfind package `x.y`.  You can see examples of subpackages such as `compier-libs.bytecomp` by `ocamlfind list`.

Comment: A typo above:  it is bit module hierarchy => it is not module hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

This means, that once a library is built and installed it will be accessible via the findlib as `parent_name.library_name`. As far as I know, this field doesn't imply any dependency, so I'm not sure that phrase "will be built as its parent" is actually true. The only real implication, is that it will be included as a [subpackage](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/findlib-1.6.2/doc/guide-html/x338.html) of the parent library, so that it will not have its own META file (that might be very useful, if you want to define several libraries in the same folder)